# Delete specific Indices in HDF5 from all groups/datasets and save the new data in same structure in h5 format

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I want to delete some `indices(rows)` from all the datasets in my `HDF5` file.

The structure of my `HDF5` is given in the picture:

[image: The structure of my HDF5 is given in the picture].

I have a number of groups and a number of datasets in each group. Some groups have subgroups that contain the datasets. The total number of rows in each dataset is the same, so the indices of the rows I want to remove are the same. I want to save the `HDF5` file with the same structure as the old one. I am unable to find an efficient way or code to do it.

Comment: To clarify: you want to create a NEW HDF5 file with the modified datasets and keep the original file as-is. Correct? If you know the row indices in advance, you can use a generator to walk the data structure, read each dataset (use slice notation to copy the data you want keep), then write to the new file.

Comment: BTW, do you care if the code is written with the `h5py` or `pytables` package? I ask because `pytables` has functions to walk the nodes, and you have to write a generator to do the same with `h5py`. Not hard, just a little more work. Also, you didn't say if any of the groups or datasets have attributes attached. If so, those will also need to be copied. Again, not hard, just more coding.

Comment: I don't think there's any  shortcuts.  You'll need to read all datasets, delete the rows, and write them to a new file.  How you delete rows will depend on what you are deleting - one or two rows, many blocks or slices etc.  `np.delete` may be useful in some cases, but simply loading a subset of rows might be better in others.